# Python: ImmutableDenseNDimArray' object has no attribute 'coeff'

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

Problem: 'ImmutableDenseNDimArray' object has no attribute 'coeff'

Algo Description:

Step1: Simply the quadratic equations with a different set of values (x0, x1, x2, xd) and variable2
Step2: Extract the coefficients of the multiple quadratic equations
Step3: Find the roots of the quadratic equation

Solving the quadratic equation individually is simple, but to generate roots for multiple quadratic equations using a loop is getting difficult and facing error as'ImmutableDenseNDimArray' object has no attribute 'coeff'.
I am a beginner to python, could some help me to get rid of this error.
Expectation: If the below solution is incorrect, How we can find the coefficients of multiple quadratic equations using a for loop

```
import math
import sympy as sym

x_input = np.zeros(12, 100)
variable2 = 10

#The values of x0, x1, x3 and xd are dynamically generated values in my code, for simplication, values are written manually
x0 = [1 ,2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12] 
x1 = [1 ,2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
x2 = [1 ,2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
xd = [1 ,2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

for i in range(12):
    x_input = sym.symbols('x_input')
    #Quadratic Equation
    quadratic_exp = ((x2[i] - xd[i]) * (abs(x_input) - x0[i])**2) + (2*x1[i])*(xd[i] * abs(x_input)) - 2*x1[i])*variable2
    # Simplified Quadratic Equation
    quadratic_exp_smpfy = sym.simplify(quadratic_exp)
    # Finding Coefficients of Polynomial 2nd order equation
    x_input_A = quadratic_exp_smpfy.coeff(x_input, 2)
    x_input_B = quadratic_exp_smpfy.coeff(x_input, 1)
    x_input_C = quadratic_exp_smpfy.coeff(x_input, 0)
```

Comment: You can't use functions from numpy and math libraries with sympy objects. So, you should leave out `x_input = np.zeros(12, 100)`. `quadratic_exp_smpfy = sym.simplify(quadratic_exp)` is unnecessary, because `quadratic_exp` already is sympy expression as it uses sympy symbols.  Apart from a missing opening bracket in `quadratic_exp = ((x2[i] ...` your code seems to work. What exactly is the issue you encountered?

Comment: Note that due to the 'abs' function, your expression isn't an ordinary polynomial.  If you declare `x_input = sym.symbols('x_input', real=True)`, `abs`gets simplified away by the even powers, but for odd powers it will still be there.